# kde5 on ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Tags: 14.04, kde5

How can I install kde5 on ubuntu 14.04 Trusty is there any stable version for 14.04 trusty?
I search on google and found a ppa repo that contaion kde5 but ppa is unstable and since Dec, 05 2014, project neon is no more available as a PPA.

Comment: If you can not find a ppa you would have to build it from source. If you want a preview, try kubuntu 15.04 or the Fedora KDE or jam spin, they are all using Plasma 5 (still KDE 4)